# Ошибка при работе с библиотекой для анимации ( при прокрутке ) aos

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-animation

Частично работает анимация ( появляются не все блоки, лучше заметно на данном примере: https://kenan.agency/test-stack/ ( проявляется, когда ширина экрана меньше 500 пикселей )

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
     lots: [
      {
            img: 'https://envato-shoebox-0.imgix.net/2a41/93b3-6f8b-4f1c-8767-cd9772b4ded7/kave+310.jpg?w=500&h=278&fit=crop&crop=edges&auto=compress%2Cformat&s=fbc0d75299d7cfda0b3c60ea52ba4aaf',
            header: 'Десерты'
          },
          {
            img: 'https://envato-shoebox-0.imgix.net/2a41/93b3-6f8b-4f1c-8767-cd9772b4ded7/kave+310.jpg?w=500&h=278&fit=crop&crop=edges&auto=compress%2Cformat&s=fbc0d75299d7cfda0b3c60ea52ba4aaf',
            header: 'Десерты'
          },
          {
            img: 'https://envato-shoebox-0.imgix.net/2a41/93b3-6f8b-4f1c-8767-cd9772b4ded7/kave+310.jpg?w=500&h=278&fit=crop&crop=edges&auto=compress%2Cformat&s=fbc0d75299d7cfda0b3c60ea52ba4aaf',
            header: 'Десерты'
          },
          {
            img: 'https://envato-shoebox-0.imgix.net/2a41/93b3-6f8b-4f1c-8767-cd9772b4ded7/kave+310.jpg?w=500&h=278&fit=crop&crop=edges&auto=compress%2Cformat&s=fbc0d75299d7cfda0b3c60ea52ba4aaf',
            header: 'Десерты'
          },
          {
            img: 'https://envato-shoebox-0.imgix.net/2a41/93b3-6f8b-4f1c-8767-cd9772b4ded7/kave+310.jpg?w=500&h=278&fit=crop&crop=edges&auto=compress%2Cformat&s=fbc0d75299d7cfda0b3c60ea52ba4aaf',
            header: 'Десерты'
          },
          {
            img: 'https://envato-shoebox-0.imgix.net/2a41/93b3-6f8b-4f1c-8767-cd9772b4ded7/kave+310.jpg?w=500&h=278&fit=crop&crop=edges&auto=compress%2Cformat&s=fbc0d75299d7cfda0b3c60ea52ba4aaf',
            header: 'Десерты'
          },
          {
            img: 'https://envato-shoebox-0.imgix.net/2a41/93b3-6f8b-4f1c-8767-cd9772b4ded7/kave+310.jpg?w=500&h=278&fit=crop&crop=edges&auto=compress%2Cformat&s=fbc0d75299d7cfda0b3c60ea52ba4aaf',
            header: 'Десерты'
          },
          {
            img: 'https://envato-shoebox-0.imgix.net/2a41/93b3-6f8b-4f1c-8767-cd9772b4ded7/kave+310.jpg?w=500&h=278&fit=crop&crop=edges&auto=compress%2Cformat&s=fbc0d75299d7cfda0b3c60ea52ba4aaf',
            header: 'Десерты'
          },
          {
            img: 'https://envato-shoebox-0.imgix.net/2a41/93b3-6f8b-4f1c-8767-cd9772b4ded7/kave+310.jpg?w=500&h=278&fit=crop&crop=edges&auto=compress%2Cformat&s=fbc0d75299d7cfda0b3c60ea52ba4aaf',
            header: 'Десерты'
          },
     ]
  },
  created() {
    AOS.init()
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
  
  .g-main__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; }
.g-article {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px #22264b;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end; }
  .g-article h3 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 0 -1px;
    padding: 100px 0 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #22264b, transparent); }
  .g-article:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 170px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.3.4/aos.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.3.4/aos.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<main id="app">
  <section class="g-main">
    <div class="g-head">
      <span>
        Меню
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="g-main__wrapper">
      <article class="g-article" v-for="( item, i ) in lots" :key="i" :style="`background: url(${item.img}) no-repeat center / cover`" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="400" :data-aos-delay="200 * i" data-aos-anchor-placement="top-bottom">
        <h3>
          {{ item.header }}
        </h3>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть исходный код aos то можно найти такую функцию. Особое внимание следует обратить на назначение обработчика события скролла окна. Именно этот обработчик отвечает за установку/снятия классов, которые скрывают или отображают элемент.

```
const initializeScroll = function initializeScroll() {
  // Extend elements objects in $aosElements with their positions
  $aosElements = prepare($aosElements, options);
  // Perform scroll event, to refresh view and show/hide elements
  handleScroll($aosElements);

  /**
   * Handle scroll event to animate elements on scroll
   */
  window.addEventListener(
    'scroll',
    throttle(() => {
      handleScroll($aosElements, options.once);
    }, options.throttleDelay)
  );

  return $aosElements;
};
```

На вашей странице это событие не происходит. Сделайте страницу с прокруткой, изменив свои стили

```
html, body {
    /* height: 100%; */
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}

main {
    /* overflow-y: scroll; */
    /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь) Была мысля, что в этом трабл, но руки не добрались решить её :C